# SendMessage WM_KEYDOWN doesn't always work

Tags: c++, delphi, winapi

I'm trying to make a program that is sending some keypresses to a window of some game. A bot if you like. I'm using SendMessage/PostMessage WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP with proper lParam to that window. The other method I've tried is to use SendInput. And Send/Post with SetKeyboardState.

The problem is that all methods work the same way - not always. I mean that I'm trying to send VK_F9 to that window every 10 seconds using a timer. It can work 3 times, or 5 times, or zero times. That means after a random Sends or Posts it stops working. But if I press F9 on my keyboard the next Send works!

What can be a problem there? May be there is some state that I'm not aware of?

Thanks in advance!

In C++ I've tried this one:

```
void GenerateKey(int vk, BOOL bExtended) {

KEYBDINPUT  kb = {0};
INPUT       Input = {0};

/* Generate a "key down" */
if (bExtended) { kb.dwFlags  = KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY; }
kb.wVk  = vk;
Input.type  = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
Input.ki  = kb;
SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(Input));
Sleep(300);

/* Generate a "key up" */
ZeroMemory(&kb, sizeof(KEYBDINPUT));
ZeroMemory(&Input, sizeof(INPUT));
kb.dwFlags  =  KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
if (bExtended) { kb.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY; }
kb.wVk = vk;
Input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
Input.ki = kb;
SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(Input));

return;
}
```

In Delphi I used this:

```
procedure FKey(Win:THandle; key:integer; special: boolean);
var
lParam: LongInt;
begin
 lParam := MakeLong(0, MapVirtualKey(key, 0));
 if (special) then
    lParam:=lParam or $1000000;
 SendMessage(Win,WM_KEYDOWN,key,lParam);
 SendMessage(Win,WM_KEYUP,key,$C0000000);
end;
```

P.S.: May be a clue - the Logitech X7 mouse with macros works just fine.

Comment: It's strongly advised to find out if the program offers any application interface or scripting solution, before you start automating it's user interface. Apart from that, SendInput and SendMessage or PostMessage should do the trick unless there's something wrong with keyboard focus, handles or ignored UI messages.

Comment: As I've said this is a game window. Direct3D window without controls. Handle is not changing :)

Comment: SendInput is designed to let you put sequence of keyboard events in queue without interleaving real ones. But you choose not to do that. The Sleep(100) is inexplicable. Send an array of input events.

Comment: I've tried everything. I've added Sleep() to simulate even the time between events. It changed nothing.
The problem is - it works for 3-5 times and stops.

Comment: I suggest you learn about queues. Why would you need to simulate time between events?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I simulated it for that game. I've thought that may be it has some kind of defence against bots.